# Select a series of data where one or more instance breaches a threshold

Tags: sql, oracle, db2

I have a SQL table (Oracle and DB2) containing process statistics from many servers. To keep it simple lets say it has:

```
Timestamp  | Server   | PID | Command_line | CPU_Usage
1385101402,  hosta,     489,  init,          0.3 
1385101399,  hosta,     264,  perl test.pl,  32
1385102402,  hosta,     489,  init,          0.3 
1385102399,  hosta,     264,  perl test.pl,  22
1385103402,  hosta,     489,  init,          0.3 
1385103402,  hostb,     489,  init,          0.2 
1385103399,  hosta,     264,  perl test.pl,  17
1385104402,  hosta,     489,  init,          0.1
1385104402,  hostb,     489,  init,          0.2
1385104399,  hosta,     264,  perl test.pl,  4
1385105402,  hosta,     489,  init,          0.3
1385105402,  hostc,     489,  init,          0.3
1385105399,  hosta,     264,  perl test.pl,  42
1385106402,  hosta,     489,  init,          0.5
1385106399,  hosta,     264,  perl test.pl,  52
```

I want to produce a meaningful chart, but as you can imagine this table is big. So what I am trying to do is extract only details for processes that exceed 50% CPU. This is easily done for data points (WHERE "CPU_Usage" > 50) But that of course only shows them when they are above 50%, prior history and subsequent performance under 50% don't make the chart.

Want I want is that any PID+Command_Line tupple, found to have exceeded 50% CPU gets all available data retrieved.  So in this example, I would want all the sample for the process with PID 264, as it breached the threshold. The rest I want to ignore

Comment: Can you provide some data?

Comment: And also provide the DBMS system you are using

Comment: This needs to work on Oracle and DB2. The data is rather larger than the example but something typical

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See a working [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3b7e1/2/0) for oracle. I am not sure about DB2.

```
WITH DATASET
    AS (SELECT 489 AS PID, 0.3 AS PERCENTAGES FROM DUAL UNION ALL
        SELECT 264 AS PID, 32 AS PERCENTAGES FROM DUAL UNION ALL
        SELECT 489 AS PID, 0.3 AS PERCENTAGES FROM DUAL UNION ALL
        SELECT 264 AS PID, 22 AS PERCENTAGES FROM DUAL UNION ALL
        SELECT 489 AS PID, 0.3 AS PERCENTAGES FROM DUAL UNION ALL
        SELECT 489 AS PID, 0.2 AS PERCENTAGES FROM DUAL UNION ALL
        SELECT 264 AS PID, 17 AS PERCENTAGES FROM DUAL UNION ALL
        SELECT 489 AS PID, 0.1 AS PERCENTAGES FROM DUAL UNION ALL
        SELECT 489 AS PID, 0.2 AS PERCENTAGES FROM DUAL UNION ALL
        SELECT 264 AS PID, 4 AS PERCENTAGES FROM DUAL UNION ALL
        SELECT 489 AS PID, 0.3 AS PERCENTAGES FROM DUAL UNION ALL
        SELECT 489 AS PID, 0.3 AS PERCENTAGES FROM DUAL UNION ALL
        SELECT 264 AS PID, 42 AS PERCENTAGES FROM DUAL UNION ALL
        SELECT 489 AS PID, 0.5 AS PERCENTAGES FROM DUAL UNION ALL
        SELECT 264 AS PID, 52 AS PERCENTAGES FROM DUAL)
SELECT
      *
FROM
      DATASET B
WHERE
      B.PID IN (SELECT
                    A.PID
              FROM
                    DATASET A
              WHERE
                    A.PERCENTAGES > 50)
```